# How to predict world position of moving Object (Velocity)?

Tags: physics, game-physics, cannon.js, ammo.js

I have a rigidbody created with cannon.js where i apply velocity on to move it.

```
this.body.velocity.set(coord.x, this.body.velocity.y, coords.z);
```

Now i want to predict the future position of this object before velocity was set.

I tried something like:

```
body.position += velocity * dt
```

This is actually not working. Wondering if someone has an idea how to do this.

Comment: You want to predict the position after how much time?
How comes you are using coord.x and coord.z as the rigidbody's velocity? Is coord a speed you calculated beforehand?

Comment: coord.x and coord.z is cartesians calculated before based on accleration.

Comment: Understood. You say you want to predict the position of the object. But how much time ahead you want to predict? Afer one second? In the next cycle?

Comment: Actually i need both, the next step and the value based on xy ms in the future.

Comment: `futurePosition = body.position + body.velocity * t` should work, where `t` is the time in seconds for the prediction.

Comment: If you know latest several points, you can estimate next point using 5 point stencil if movement has acceleration.

Comment: Your code and question are worded incredibly poorly. You need to tell us what `coord` and `coords` are and why you are applying them to velocity. Also, the timing of the answer you want is near impossible to get at because you are asking for something in the future that won't happen before what you are doing now.

I am going to assume your English isn't very good and you are essentially asking for the equation for the position of projectiles with constant acceleration which is:

x(t) = 0.5*a*t^2 + v_0*t + x_0

Answer (score 0):

To get the position in the future: newpos = position + velocity*amtseconds. 
To get the position in the next timestep: newpos = position + velocity*deltatime.